# Merge without dissolve in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, merge, multipart, adjacency

I am trying to merge several polygons in a feature dataset into one. Normally I would use a simple merge but the issue is that merge automatically dissolves. I on the other hand want to have them all represented by one single record, but maintain their existing boundaries.The top image is what happens. But the bottom image is what I want. As mentioned originally the left would represent by two separate selectable polygons and the right is the output being one record/one selectable polygon.

[image: This is what happens when you merge. One record is created from two existing records.]

[image: This is what I want to happen. I want to merge the two together but maintain both polygons entire existing boundaries. Although now I want it to be one record]

Comment: Topologically speaking, what you ask isn't possible. Parts can't overlap. Even if you could generate such a shape, it wouldn't render correctly, and attempting any sort of operation on it would cause spectacular failures, far worse than having a ring not wound in the correct direction.

Comment: Reference:  http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=25355 `a) The interiors of 2 Polygons that are elements of a MultiPolygon may not intersect.` You can express your geometry as GeometryCollection but I do not know if ArcGIS can handle those. Example: `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION ( POLYGON (( 418 357, 418 359, 420 359, 420 357, 418 357 )), POLYGON (( 419 356, 419 358, 421 358, 421 356, 419 356 )))`